# лямбда аргумент в std::sort ( ошибка C2280) [сортировка статического вектора структур]

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, sdl, struct

https://github.com/LAGx/simpllight/tree/errors/simpll..
(файл `windows.cpp/windows.h`)

класс `window` содержит статическое поле вектора структур. структура имеет два поля, одно из которых имеет `int` значение. Всё, что нужно это отсортировать вектор по этому значению.
Делать я это пытаюсь с помощью `std::sort`, лямбда функции. Именно в этой функции и возникает проблема. пишет, что аргумент ссылается на удаленную функцию (`с2280`).

Я предполагаю, что это из за статического поля (ибо в мейн такая конструкция работает). как с этим бороться? Место с ошибкой:

```
sort(allDrawable.begin(), allDrawable.end(), [](const ToDraw& a, const ToDraw& b) {
    return a.depth < b.depth;
});
```

структура и класс:

```
struct ToDraw {
    sf::Drawable &image;
    signed int depth = 0;
};

class Window {
private:

public:
    sf::RenderWindow canvas;
    sf::View view;

    static std::vector<ToDraw> allDrawable;

    Window();

    void drawAll();//make sort allDrawable by depth

    ~Window();
};
```

вся функция, в которой возникает ошибка:

```
void Window::drawAll() {
canvas.clear(State::mainColorMajor);

sort(allDrawable.begin(), allDrawable.end(), [](const ToDraw& a, const ToDraw& b) {
    return a.depth < b.depth;
});

for (int i = 0; i < allDrawable.size(); i++)
    canvas.draw(allDrawable[i].image);

canvas.display();
allDrawable.clear();
}
```

Comment: Предположу, что у вас ошибка в canvas.draw(), где идет обращение к ссылке. Скорее всего, она не валидна

Comment: Error C2280 'spl::ToDraw &spl::ToDraw::operator =(const spl::ToDraw &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

если закомментировать canvas, то ничего не происходит. Если sort, то ошибка пропадает. Ошибка явно в sort.

Comment: Извиняюсь, подумал что проблема с крашем связана. У вас оператор присваивания не определен из-за наличи ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная структура имеет член данных ссылочного типа - `image`

```
struct ToDraw {
    sf::Drawable &image;
    signed int depth = 0;
};
```

Поэтому для этой структуры объявленный неявно копирующий оператор присваивания определен как удаленный. В результате нельзя применить сортировку к объектам данной структуры в виду отсутствия копирующего оператора присваивания.

Вы могли бы вместо ссылки на объект типа `sf::Drawable` объявить указатель на соответствующий тип. И тогда сортировка была бы возможной.